# SKype integration and fetch all details from skpeaccount in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, skype

Is it possible to integrate skype is IOS application.
I know it is possible with the below code:-

```
- (IBAction)skypeMe:(id)sender
{
  BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
  if(installed)
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
  }
  else
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];
  }
}
```

But is it possible to fetch the call details or the contact details or chat history from the skpye account.

Or to fetch the skype name,id and password used in the skpye can be fetch through application and stored in database.

Like we do in facebook.through facebook API.Fetching contact details etc.

Comment: Its not integration...But you just open the Skype App.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [Skype Developer](http://dev.skype.com/desktop-api-reference) site for further help.

[Skype SDKs and APIs on Mobile devices is prohibited](http://devforum.skype.com/t5/Developer-Corner/Integrating-in-mobile-apps/td-p/13340) refer it.

Answer (score -1):

Currently there isn't any public api available for ios for Skype.  So, you can't achieve your desire, thogh you can refer [Skype URI Tutorial: iOS Apps](http://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/skype-uri-tutorial-ios)

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: what do you mean by IMHO???? & I know he is already doing what I'm suggesting but it contains more information. It's useful too.